# Selecting random rows from pandas dataframe based on counts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like below:

```
col1, col2, label
a,    b   , cat
b,    b1, , mouse
.
.
.........., elephant
.........., mouse
```

and the `value_counts` for label column:

```
df.dataframe.value_counts:

cat: 7599
mouse: 6458
dog: 5100
elephant: 5000
```

I want to select at least N rows from each label category at random such that my value_counts become:

```
cat: N
mouse: N
dog: N
elephant: N
```

Is there a "pandoic" way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can first shuffle your DF using [sample(frac=1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) method and then pick first N rows from each group (groupped by `label`):

```
df.sample(frac=1).groupby('label', sort=False).head(N)
```

Demo:

```
In [108]: df.sample(frac=1).groupby('label', sort=False).head(3)
Out[108]:
    col1 label
11     9     a
28     4     a
58     0     a
96     5     c
99     3     b
35     6     c
88     8     c
97     9     b
83     7     b
```

Setup:

```
In [106]: df = pd.DataFrame({'label':np.random.choice(list('abc'), 100), 'col1':np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)})

In [107]: df
Out[107]:
    col1 label
0      4     c
1      6     b
2      9     c
3      0     b
4      5     a
5      3     a
6      3     b
7      6     c
8      7     b
9      6     a
..   ...   ...
90     4     b
91     5     b
92     8     c
93     2     c
94     9     a
95     2     a
96     5     c
97     9     b
98     8     b
99     3     b

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

HINT: if you want to find the maximum possible N - you can use the following code (thank to [@NickilMaveli for the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565905/selecting-random-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-based-on-counts/41566001?noredirect=1#comment70339655_41566001))

```
N = df.label.value_counts(sort=False).min()  # (or) df.label.value_counts().iloc[-1]
```

Comment: To generalize this case for an optimal `N` value, you could add `N=df.label.value_counts(normalize=True).iloc[-1] * df.shape[0]` from which the length of the lowest count could be found to call `.head` on it.

Comment: @NickilMaveli, thank you! I've added it to the answer

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) with `groupby` if need e.g. `60%` samples per group:

```
print (df.groupby('label').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.6)))
```